# Given the output of numpy.where(), how to acquire a list of list of the indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am searching a rather large matrix for zero elements and then want to then loop over the rows and inside each row, overall the indices where I found a zero.
`numpy.where(M==0)` gives me `(np.array, np.array)`.

How can I format this result to my needs in the most efficient way?

```
# Output of numpy.where(M==0):
(x,y) = (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([2, 3, 1, 2, 1]))
# Output I want, each value of y in the list corresponding to the x value:
wanted = [[2,3],[1,2],[1],[]]
```

I have thought about constructing a sparse matrix out of the output (since `M` is dense, `M==0` should be sparse), but don't know how I would iterate over the rows there.

```
zeros = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones((len(x),)), (x,y)), shape=M.shape)
print(zeros.nonzero()) # is the same output as np.where, so it does not help me
```

I suppose I could slice into each row and `.nonzero()` it, but I hope there is something more efficient

Edit: Alternatively, a dictionary of the form `{x_value:[list of corresponding y_values]}` would work as well

Comment: could you elaborate on how the `wanted` values are obtained?

Comment: they are not obtained, they are an example of the format I would like to get my values in: Each row i has a list wanted[i] containing the column indexes for which it is zero

Comment: Look at `argwhere`, which just does `np.transpose(np.nonzero(...))1`.  Flat iteration on that 2d array is just as good (or bad) as your proposed double loop.

Comment: @hpaulj the second for loop would be in a function, since I need to load from a database for each row and would like to group them by row because of this

Comment: Just iterate on the row indices.  While they remain the same, collect the column values in a list.  When they change, call the column function with that list.

Comment: I found that `defaultdict(list)` does just what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) allowed me to iterate my tuples into a dict as I wanted.

```py
indices = np.argwhere(M==0)
zeros = defaultdict(list)
for coords in indices:
    zeros[coords[0]].append(coords[1])
print(zeros)
```

```
# Output:
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1], 1: [1, 2], 2: [0, 3]})
```